# java.rmi.NotBoundException . Discovering what bindings are available

Tags: java, rmi

Below are the bindings of implementation of java.rmi.registry.Registry

```
CustomRegistry: registryCount = 2
reg1.com:11, # of bindings = 2
 OPTIONS
 UPDATES
reg2.com:11, # of bindings = 1
 TEST
```

When I use

```
(MyRegistry)registry.lookup("OPTIONS");
```

I receive exception: `java.rmi.NotBoundException: OPTIONS`

After reading explanations of this exception on this site then it appears the binding "OPTIONS" is not discoverable.

As the RMI servers are on a different machine is there a mechanism  I can use to discover the bindings available on servers reg1.com % reg2.com

Comment: I don't know what 'implementation of `java.rmi.registry.Registry`' means, but all RMI bindings are discoverable by definition, with `Registry.list()` and/or `Registry.lookup()`, or the same operations with the `Naming` class. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP So since the RMI binding "OPTIONS" exists what other reason could java.rmi.NotBoundException be thrown ?

Comment: Bug in your code, of course. Post it. Edit it into your question, including the part that produced the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After reading explanations of this exception on this site then it appears the binding "OPTIONS" is not discoverable.

No it doesn't. It means it isn't bound.

> As the RMI servers are on a different machine

Irrelevant.

> is there a mechanism I can use to discover the bindings available on servers reg1.com % reg2.com

`Registry.list().` Any string returned by `Registry.list()` can be plugged directly into `Registry.lookup()` to return the binding, unless it was unbound in between, which isn't likely.

Similarly any string returned by `Naming.list()` can be plugged into `Naming.lookup().`

*But* you can't mix them up, e.g. passing a string returned by `Registry.list()` to `Naming.lookup(),` because `Naming` deals in RMI URLs where `Registry` just deals in names.

Comment: thanks. by Registry.list() -> Naming.lookup() do you mean Registry.list() is not equal to Naming.lookup() ?

Comment: I mean passing a string returned by `Registry.list()` to `Naming.lookup()`.